# deleting rows of a data frame with specific condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I've seen similar questions here, but I couldn't find any help.

I have a df like this:

```
df <- data.frame(CSF1=c(-9,-9,-9,-9), CSF2=c(-9,-1,-9,-9), 
               D13S1=c(-9,-9,11,11), D13S2=c(-9,-9,11,12))

         CSF1 CSF2 D13S1 D13S2 
10398     -9   -9   -9    -9                   
10398     -9   -1   -9    -9                             
20177     -9   -9   11    11                  
20361     -9   -9   11    12
```

I want to delete all the rows with values -9 or -1 for all columns, like the first 2 rows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (edited by Arun to account for Dov's post):

```
df[rowSums(df == -1 | df == -9, na.rm = TRUE) != ncol(df), ]
##   CSF1 CSF2 D13S1 D13S2
## 3   -9   -9    11    11
## 4   -9   -9    11    12
```

`(df == -1 | df == -9)` will give you logical matrix. `rowSums` will give you count of `TRUE` in each row since `TRUE` is evaluated as `1`. The `na.rm=TRUE` is to ensure that rows with `NA` are not omitted (see Dov's post). Use resultant row numbers to subset `df`.

Answer (score 3):

All I will add is that the `which` function doesn't appear to be necessary. Removing it yields the same result.

There is a secondary problem that you would have in situations with missing data. If, you add an `NA` to the 3rd row (try it with `df[3,4] <- NA`), then the output of the above solution will omit the 3rd row as well regardless of the other entries' values. I won't suggest alternatives as this may not be a problem for your data set.

Comment: Dov, I think you should suggest alternatives. That's the point of SO (to get the *best* answer) :).